# Group Count in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking for a way to display a table where a set of multiple attributes appear more than one time.

For example, suppose I had a table, Tbl1 with attributes A, B, C, D, E
How do I make a query such that it only shows rows where A, B, C appear more than once (as in the same A, B, C as a group), but D and E may or may not be different?

My attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl1
WHERE COUNT(A, B, C) > 1
```

and I get an error: "group function is not allowed here"

Comment: Which database product are you using?

Comment: "Oracle SQL Developer" is not a DBMS, it's a SQL client - and one which can connect to different DBMS. So it's still unclear which DBMS you are using (if you had supplied the exact error message we could have at least deduct it from that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: based on the error messages the OP is getting, it appears that the DBMS is, in fact, Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is, that you cannot use this grouping in the `WHERE`-part of an sql clause.

```
SELECT colums
FROM tables
WHERE condition
```

the condition refers to a single row of the table.

What you want is `HAVING`

```
SELECT colums
FROM tables
HAVING condition
```

The condition after `HAVING` is evaluated **after** the grouping and there you can use aggregation functions like `COUNT` or `SUM`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GROUP BY` clause (SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx, MySQL: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm).

Within each group, you'll want to get get the count of rows in that group (using `COUNT(*)`) and then use a `HAVING` clause to filter on that count. `HAVING` is like a `WHERE` clause for `GROUP BY`. It filters on the results of the grouping, and can make reference to the grouped columns (in this case, A, B and C), or any aggregates (in this case, `COUNT(*)`).

Here's what your query could look like. Note that you can only include columns in the `SELECT` field list that are mentioned in the `GROUP BY` or that are contained in aggregate functions such as `COUNT()` and `MAX()`. MySQL will let you get away with putting other columns in, but SQL Server will give you an error. It's best to follow this rule even if the database allows it.

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       C,
       COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
  FROM Tbl1
 GROUP BY A, B, C
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you want the full rows where this is true, then you can used a derived table:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Tbl1
  JOIN (
    SELECT A,
           B,
           C,
           COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
      FROM Tbl1
     GROUP BY A, B, C
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) AS duplicates
    ON duplicates.A = Tbl1.A AND
       duplicates.B = Tbl1.B AND
       duplicates.C = Tbl1.C
```

Comment: I get "not a GROUP BY expression" error in the select row. Idk if this makes a huge difference, but I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: It does matter, as each database product may have different rules for these kinds of things. That said, I'm not sure why you'd be getting any errors for this, as this is pretty bog-standard SQL.

Comment: with the new one, it says "missing expression" at  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with my SQL. Maybe you can post what you are actually using. Perhaps an Oracle expert will show up.

Comment: To what I am aware, this is connected to an actual oracle database. I did have a temporary fix yesterday by joining the table to itself over attributes "A, B, C" and "D, E" != "D, E"

Comment: @KyleGrage: it'd be really great if you could post the actual SQL you are using so we can diagnose the error messages. I've looked at the Oracle docs and I see nothing wrong with what I've posted. I think you're adding things or not giving us the full picture. You shouldn't need a self-join to do this.